# MS Visual Studio Code does not provide “Configure Tasks” option

Tags: visual-studio

In MS Visual Studio Code, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> brings up a list of options / actions.  This list should include "Configure Tasks", but in my installation does not.  Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: "Configure Tasks" is only available in version 1.13 and earlier. What version of VS code do you have?